# EOSIO transaction propagation model

Tags: transactions

I try to understand how EOS (mainnet) propagates transactions.
Before a transaction gets included in a block,
is (thus pending) transaction actively propagated peer-by-peer regardless
of peers being producing or non-producing?

Also, is there a way to monitor incoming transactions (before included in block) from my peers? I have looked into documentations of NODEOS and CLEOS and was not able to find a way.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are propagated by the active Block Producer in accordance with the production schedule. Any transactions broadcasted to an API node are relayed to the active producer.

In nodeos, you can set the [read mode](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/read-modes) to `speculative` to see transactions that have been included in blocks but not yet validated (unconfirmed transactions).

Comment: Thank you Sandwich. Is there a way to see transactions that are NOT YET included in blocks? I'm thinking about (indirectly) measuring the transaction completion time. I see when the transactions get included in blocks. However, I'm not sure if I can observe the same transactions in the EOS network before they get included in blocks. More specifically, if I run a EOS node (producing or non-producing) and peering with BP's nodes, will I get a chance to get those transactions (not yet included in blocks)  from my peers?